# forwarded port on localhost still up after closing session

Tags: ssh, localhost, port-forwarding, tunnel

I'm new to ssh port forwarding, so I was checking [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) out. I did as the "Local Port Forwarding" section said, except I did this:

```
george@george-pc:~$ ssh -L 12345:www.ubuntuforums.org:80 george
```

I pointed Chrome to *localhost:12345* and it gave the expected result. However, after I closed the session (had to reboot the pc) and pointed the browser again to *localhost:12345*, it still redirected me to the site.

Is this normal ? How to fix this ?

Comment: I doubt it. Did you clear your browser cache first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that browser caching is providing the illusion of an ongoing connection. I performed a couple of experiments which seem to confirm that.

If I open the same page via `localhost:12345` in a different browser (Firefox) after the ssh session exits (without opening it that way while the ssh session is active, that connection fails. If I open the page in Firefox while the ssh session is active, I see the same behavior I see in Chrome (the page loads again after the ssh session exits).

The other experiment was this command:

```
telnet localhost 12345
```

That connection succeeds while the ssh session is active, and gets the expected connection refusal after it exits. I suspect `telnet` is a more reliable test for whether the port forwarding is active than any web browser.